# dynamic creation of class at runtime from file

Tags: java, class, dynamic

I'm looking for a possibility to load the Java code dynamically into a
class at the run time. The Java Code should be readed from an
XML-file. There are just some "If-Then" expressions and should be
added into one class and use it like any other class in my project.

Actually my file contains some rule codes which i want to load like cache and use 
this class further

Does someone know if it is possible in java?

best regards
Abhij

Comment: May I ask why the code is in XML?

Comment: Good god(s) consider using a Groovy, JRuby, etc DSL instead: *way* less work, and much easier to deal with.

Comment: Actually it contain some ruleCode of organization like  C01|((customer=registered) and (sales>70000))                      then it is of type C01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do this with [CGLib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cglib/), but I haven't done more than use it to mock classes at runtime.  If dynamic code is a major aspect of your application you should consider using a language like Ruby which has much better support for running code read in at runtime.

Comment: As a script language you can use http://www.beanshell.org/ - it's syntax is very Java-like

Comment: You could also use javassist, or just leverage the existing java compilation api... But I agree using a dynamic language is a better solution.